# MEAN stack error. "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: angular, express, routes, mean

I have a MEAN stack application I am trying to troubleshoot. I have isolated the problem but I am not sure how to fix it here is the code. The position I believe the error is at is marked as such.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-success',
  templateUrl: './success.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./success.component.css']
})
export class SuccessComponent implements OnInit {
  user:Object;

  constructor(
    private authService:AuthService,
    private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => { //THIS CALL TO GET PROFILE CAUSES THE ERROR
      console.log("GOT HERE (IN SUCCESS)");
      this.user = profile.user;
    },
    err => {
      console.log("ERROR" + err);
      return false;
    });
  }

  onLogoutClick(){
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

With the get Profile() method here

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  registerUser(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
  }

  authenticateUser(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProfile() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    console.log("GOT HERE (IN getProfile)");
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/success', {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()); //PROBLEM IS HERE
  }

  loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
  }

  storeUserData(token, user) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
    console.log("GOT HERE...");
  }

  logout() {
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have seen similar posts but they haven't helped me in this case.

Also here is the route

```
router.get('/success', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next) => {
    const user = req.user;
    console.log("GOT HERE (IN the route file)");
    return res.json({user: user});
    //return res.json({success: true, msg: 'user is found'});
});
```

Comment: The Error looks like this:                                                        
events.js:165
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: where is ```loadToken()``` ?

Comment: I edited it in sorry for not including whole file

Comment: try not to return: just  ```res.json({user: user});```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing almost everything right, but you don't have to set the content-type from angular service. Angular will do that job automatically for you.

In the case where you are trying to send your auth token with your api request, try the following pattern.

Instead of calling your function to load the token for you try calling the localstorage directly from your function.

**Example**

```
getProfile() {
  const headers = new Headers()
  .set('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
  console.log("GOT HERE (IN getProfile)");
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/success', {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()); //PROBLEM IS HERE
}
```

Or if you want you can initialize a variable in your service file and get that value only once from the local storage.

```
token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
```

Updating my answer so that you can use the new HttpClient which angular provides.

Import the new HttpClient module and then create the object in your constructor

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Comment: @VirgilMartinez yes.. I have placed a semicolon after Headers() by mistakely edited my answer

Comment: I am receiving this error "Argument of type '{ headers: void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Headers'."

Comment: const headers = new Headers().set('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('id_token')); do it like this, also make sure that your token exists in your local storage.

Comment: I did that, but I am still receiving the same error. For some reason, it is setting it to void.

Comment: Please check your local storage, as i have also seen that you are using the old http
try to use the new one import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Please check my updated answer and also confirm your localstorage data

Comment: Lets chat somewhere else so that i can help you.